# Did you have both Unity and classic Gnome in 11.04?

Tags: discussion

in 11.04 I remember that we had both the classic desktop and Unity as a pre-installed option of desktop. But in all questions I find there's the Unity ones **from 11.04** and the old ones **until 10.10**.

What did we really have? and what should we recommend to use for situations like these.

[Here's an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/31/10698) I thought should have been **until 11.04**.

I want to know on what version we should set GNOME Classic and on which to say Unity. Should we have both? Or should we just call them GNOME CLASSIC?

*@warriorIng64 spoke my mind*

I just want a general answer, because right now it's a mess!

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here - can you please explain in more detail? :)

Comment: @jrg I think he's asking whether answers which describe the use of Ubuntu Classic (GNOME 2) session in 11.04 are valid, versus a response saying how to do the same thing in Unity.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Ah. Ok, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think, unless the questioner explicitly wants to know how to do any task in GNOME 2, we can safely assume that he is only interested in doing the particular task in Unity.

In simple words, if the OP doesn't ask for steps in GNOME, just answer for Unity.

Comment: but what about the current LTS? it has the old GNOME. Shouldn't we also make one for that?

Comment: If the OP doesn't mention that he wants to do it in something other than Unity, then I don't find it necessary to answer for that interface. If someone wants to do it in GNOME or anything else, they can always ask a separate question.

Comment: I just wanted a general answer to this question! I see it a lot when it comes to this type of questions.

Comment: the separate question will be a dupe and then get merged into the same one it's better to have just one question of the same subject.

Answer (score 0):

11.04 did have GNOME 2 installed as well, but on that answer I think it was edited to only go up to 10.10 since Unity is assumed to be the default interface in 11.04 onwards. It looks like it has to do with how one is able to start the Update Manager.

Comment: Since 10.04-11.04 have GNOME 2 installed by default, I think we need to have a classic GNOME answer for 10.04 and 10.10, and then a Unity answer for 11.04+, since Unity is the default there and I'd argue that anyone who moved back to 11.04 is probably savvy enough to do something like open update manager. (at least in this case)

Comment: and other questions related to versions on setting up settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should say 11.10 and GNOME classic, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you call it Gnome Fallback, Gnome Classic or Ubuntu Classic, *please* also use its proper name: Gnome Panel. It deserves more attention than it currently receives.

Your question seems to be which shells were installed by default in 11.04? That was Unity and Gnome Panel (Ubuntu Classic). In 11.10, Unity 2D replaced Gnome Panel as a secondary shell.